# Parallelism of two lines in a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle and let $D, E \in (BC), F\in (AD), G\in (AE)$ such that $m(\angle BAD)=m(\angle DAE)=m(\angle EAC)=m(\angle ABF)=m(\angle CBG)$. The bisector of $\angle ABC$ intersects $(AE)$ in $I$. Prove that:
a) $BEG$ is an isosceles triangle.
b) $AGB$ and $FDB$ are similar triangles.
c) $FI$ and $BC$ are parallel. 
I've managed to solve a) and b) and I would say that these should help me to finish c) as well. I would appreciate any tip/help with this final item.

Comment: What's the context of this problem? EG Can I use Ceva's theorem (in trigonometric form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I didn't use a) and b), and I don't think they are relevant to c).

The difficulty here is that the line $FI$ isn't nicely defined. So, we should try to work without using the line $FI$.

Approach 1:

**Hint:** Show that $F, I$ are symmetric about the height from A.
Hence, $FI \parallel BC$.

> DR SK has an elegant approach.

> The most direct way I can think of is $ \angle ACI = 20^\circ$ by Ceva's theorem.

Approach 2:
**Hint:** Show that the height of $F, I$ from base $BC$ are the same.

> The most direct way I can think of is calculating the heights using trigonometry and sine rule

> $ \sin 30^\circ \sin 40^\circ = \frac{1}{2} \times 2 \sin 20^\circ \cos 20^\circ = \sin 20^\circ \sin 70^\circ $

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinion. Solved it now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $BI$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ and hence $\angle ACI =20^{\circ}$ . Thereafter points $F$ and $I$ are symmetric about the altitude on the side $BC$ from vertex $A$ and thus $FI\parallel BC$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinion. Solved it now. :)

Comment: Oh, that's a nice observation!

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thanks!